# create virtual host for vuejs app return Invalid Host header by nginx

Tags: nginx, vue.js, virtualhost

I have some problem when try create virtual hosts for vuejs app. This is my setting:

```
# etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       vue.vavenger.local

# /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/vue.vavenger.local.conf
upstream vuejs_app {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/vue.vavenger.local.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue.vavenger.local.errors.log;

root /var/www/html/vuejs_app;
index index.html;
server_name vue.vavenger.local;

location / {
  # try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
  proxy_pass http://vuejs_app;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

and when i run my app this this command:

```
npm run serve
```

it return this error
[image]

Please give me the answer for this question. Thank so much!

Comment: the host is not given as $http_host, but just $host

Comment: hi! can you explain with more detail for this case :) thank

Comment: sure you would need to have this line proxy_set_header Host $host; instead of proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

Comment: i change $http_host to $host and then restart ngĩn. Seemingly, its not work :(

Comment: Try add it like this : proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to change `vue.config.js`

`module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}`